# Filter JSON key value and assign names to rendered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

If this is a duplicate, I apologize, I couldn't find this case anywhere.

I have an ajax call going to our ldap server which returns a JSON object like this: 
`{groups: 
  [{dn: "cn=test,ou=security,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com", isDynamicGroup: true}]`
In the response this is what I see

```
{dn: "cn=test,ou=security,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com", 
isDynamicGroup: true}
dn: "cn=test,ou=security,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com"
isDynamicGroup: true
```

I'm able to populate DOM elements just fine and style our front end, so users can click a group and load the members. However, what I'm trying to do is filter out `isDynamicGroup: false` and give those that match a separate ID/class for styling. Mainly so users know they can't send databack.

This is the group call in ajax

```
//Display groups
$(function displayGroupItems() {
  $(document).on('click', '#ldap-tab', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ldap/groups',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.groups, function(i, dn) {
                $('<li><a id="groupsList" class="panel-block dn-class">' + dn.dn + '</a></li>').appendTo('#groupSearchUl');
            });
        }
    })
  });
});
```

Right now the objects render

```
<div class="groupsList">
 <ul class="groupSearchUl">
  <li><a id="groupsList" class="panel-block dn-class">groupName</a> 
  </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I would like to see

```
<div class="groupsList">
 <ul class="groupSearchUl">
  <li><a id="groupsList dynamicgroup" class="panel-block dn- 
   class">groupName</a> 
  </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I see that the ids will be repeated.

Comment: Also, since your `data.groups` is a javascript array, using `$.each` on simple array is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out the groups with isDynamicGroup set to false you can use:

```
var dynamicGroups = data.groups.filter(group => group.isDynamicGroup);
```

If you want just to assign a class only to groups with isDynamicGroup property set to true you can use something like that:

```
$(function displayGroupItems() {
    $(document).on('click', '#ldap-tab', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ldap/groups',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                data.groups.forEach(function(group) {
                    var groupClass = "groupsList panel-block dn-class";
                    if (group.isDynamicGroup) {
                        groupClass += " dynamic-group";
                    }
                    $('<li><a class="' + groupClass + '">' + group.dn + '</a></li>').appendTo('#groupSearchUl');
                 });
            })
       });
 });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand by replacing you success callback with the following you should get what you want.

```
$.each(data.groups, function(i, dn) { $('<li><a id="groupsList" class="panel-block ' + (dn.isDynamicGroup ? 'dynamic-group' : '') + ' dn-class">' + dn.dn + '</a></li>').appendTo('#groupSearchUl'); });
```

The link will have the `dynamic-group` class if it is a dynamic group.